# How to show at least two commits which has same parent commit

Tags: git, git-commit

Title says it all. So far I've come across solution which basically shows commit and it's parent commit, but it needs further filtering. Is there better approach?

```
git rev-list --all --min-parents=1 | while read child; do parent=$(git rev-parse ${child}^); echo "$child $parent"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems a bit underspecified.

The solution presented checks only the *first* parent of each commit, but any commit can have multiple parents.  Are the multiple parents to be considered, for those commits with multiple parents?  Do we want to find *any* such commits, or *all* such commits?

The `git rev-list` command can easily produce a list of parent hash IDs that go with each child: simply add `--parents` to the options.  The post-processing filter can then use a simple associative array lookup.

Overall, the problem is similar to a directed graph arc reversal: a "transpose", "converse", or "reverse" of the directed graph.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph).